# Agregar Y Eliminar Elementos De Forma Dinámica Con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, ecmascript-6

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario dinámico que al momento de darle click a un botón de agregar, aparezca un formulario que requiere cierta información.

El detalle es que si necesito hacer mas registros, no quiero estar mandando la información, volver a llenar el formulario y estarme regresando a cada rato. Entonces se me ocurrió hacer un botón para que se este agregando dinámicamente mas lineas de formulario... lo logre hacer con un solo formulario.

Ahora como lo puedo hacer para que al darle click al botón aparezcan mas formularios?

Este es mi código al momento:

```
<div class="agregar-form">
        <button class="agregar" id="agregar"><span>+</span> Agregar Campos Para Registro de Material</button>
    </div>
    <div id="nuevo-form"></div>  



const agregar = document.getElementById('agregar');

agregar.addEventListener('click',function(){
    let formualrio; 

    formulario = `
            <form action="#" class="form-agregar" id="form-agregar">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Custom PN: </label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="custom" placeholder="Custom PN" id="custom">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Qty: </label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="qty" placeholder="Cantidad pzs" id="qty">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">PO: </label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="po" placeholder="PO" id="po">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Pallets: </label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="pallets" placeholder="Numero de Pallets" id="pallets">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">SO: </label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="so" placeholder="Sail Order" id="so">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">DN: </label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="dn" placeholder="DN" id="dn">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">#Factura: </label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="factura" placeholder="Numero de Factura" id="factura">
                </div>

                <button class="agregarForm" id="agregarForm"><span>+</span>Agregar</button>
            </form>
        <div class="btnEnviar">
            <input type="submit" value="Aceptar" id="aceptar" class="aceptar">
        </div>
    `;

    document.getElementById('nuevo-form').innerHTML = formulario;


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solamente te faltó agregar un `+=` en esta parte `document.getElementById('nuevo-form').innerHTML = formulario;` para ir concatenando en el div donde quieres que se acumulen los `from`, te dejo un ejemplo sencillo.

```js
var agregar = document.getElementById('agregar');
var contenedor = document.getElementById('nuevo-form');
var contador = 0;

agregar.addEventListener('click', function(){
contador++;

var _form = `<form action="" id="form${contador}">

  <label for="">input${contador}</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre${contador}">

</form>`;

contenedor.innerHTML += _form;


})
```

```html
<div class="agregar-form">
        <button class="agregar" id="agregar"><span>+</span> Agregar Campos Para Registro de Material</button>
    </div>
    <div id="nuevo-form"></div>
```

Comment: excelente muchas gracias si me hacia falta esa parte del +=, y con tu ejemplo ya comprendi mas lo que quiero hacer muchas gracias

Comment: No hay de qué compañero :D